# Shall I create these functions in parent component and pass them to child for a performance improvement? Or is Svelte able to "hoist" them?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

Let's say I have a component:

- Page.svelte:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  const players: Player[] = getPlayersFromSomewhere()
</script>

{#each players || [] as player}
  <Player {player} />
{/each}
```

- and Player.svelte:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  export let player: Player;
  
    async function doSomethingWithPlayer() {
    // many lines of code here...
    }

    async function doSomethingElse() {
    // many lines of code here...
    }

    async function doSomethingElseAgain() {
    // many lines of code here...
    }

  // ... many functions here
</script>

player is used here with many buttons like:

<button on:click={doSomethingWithPlayer}>...</button>
<button on:click={doSomethingElse}>...</button>
<button on:click={doSomethingElseAgain}>...</button>
```

#### THE QUESTION IS

Is Svelte recreating the functions in `Player.svelte` for each player or just one time using it for each player?

Shall I create the functions in `Page.svelte` and pass them to `Player.svelte`? Or is Svelte able to "hoist" them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Svelte will automatically hoist functions that don't depend on local component state. From [the docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action):

> Don't worry about the fact that we're redeclaring the foo function for every component instance — Svelte will hoist any functions that don't depend on local state out of the component definition.

You can see this behavior in the Svelte REPL. Consider the following component.

```svelte
<script>
    let name = 'world';
    
    function changeName() {
        name = name + 1;
    }
    
    function log() {
        console.log("I'm independent")
    }
</script>

<h1>Hello {name}!</h1>

<button on:click={changeName}>
    Change
</button>

<button on:click={log}>
    Log
</button>
```

`changeName` depends on component state, but `log` does not, so it is hoisted out of the component. You see the following in the compiled JS: there is only one `log` function, but `changeName` is created per instance.

```js
function log() {
    console.log("I'm independent");
}

function instance($$self, $$props, $$invalidate) {
    let name = 'world';

    function changeName() {
        $$invalidate(0, name = name + 1);
    }

    return [name, changeName];
}

class App extends SvelteComponent {
    constructor(options) {
        super();
        init(this, options, instance, create_fragment, safe_not_equal, {});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the module context to run code only once regardless of how many times you initialize the component. I recommend you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62239077/11858359) answer from Rich Harris and the official [module context tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/sharing-code).

Comment: Yeah. It would be great but I cannot right now because of https://github.com/FormidableLabs/urql/issues/1819.

Comment: @GeoffRich, what do you think about this anwser?